# Linq To Sql - Update not being persisted

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I am really confused about why an update is not taking place. This is very simple:

```
    int goodID = 100;

    DataContext db = new DataContext();

    Schedule schedule = db.Schedules.Single(s => s.ID == goodID);

    // this wont persist - WHY NOT?!
    schedule.Email = txtEmail.Text;

    // this does persist
    schedule.NumberCourses = 5;

    db.SubmitChanges();
```

I can't understand why the field, Email, isn't getting the value from the textbox. What can I check?

## EDIT

I have set a breakpoint and checked the value after assignment. It assigns the textbox value but still no update.

Comment: I spent the last week getting into LINQ TO SQL only to find out it has been discontinued, I'm wondering if you're aware.  I'll be switching gears to Entity Framework.

Comment: I am aware that it will not be developed on further. But they aren't planning on removing it from the framework. I am paying attention to EF, but not using it until it starts to gain speed (hopefully after the next release.) L2S is great for the small to medium apps that I work on.

Comment: Cool.. just wanted to mention it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am an idiot. It's fixed. Votes for everyone.
Instead of checking in the database, like a normal person would, I was just looking on the webform after refreshing the page. I wasn't initializing the textbox with the value from the db. So the update was happening. See? I told you I was an idiot.

Comment: Ronnie, can you share with us what the problem was? Whether you think its dumb or not, you're very unlikely to be the only one to ever have the problem and someone may be able to learn from it :)

Answer (score 2):

Check what changes will be submitted to the datacontext.

Add a breakpoint just before the `db.SubmitChanges()` line gets executed and add the following Watch:

```
db.GetChangeSet();
```

In the Watch (or Quick Watch) window you'll be able to see which changes are being submitted.

Answer (score 1):

Set a breakpoint and check the value of schedule.Email before and after that line. Also, use the immediate window to check txtEmail.Txt to see if it actually contains data.

Tell us what you find.

Comment: Can you change schedule.Email with a manual SQL query? Profile the LTS query and use that parameterized query manually as well. Again, tell us what happens :)

Answer (score 1):

Does that dbml match the database table? If it doesn't match the database, you can get weird things. Try reimporting it.